# Python merge audio tracks to play at the same time

Tags: python, audio, merge, python-playsound

I am working on music software that uses individual audio files for each note in the scale. I use the playsound module to then play these notes in the sequence constructed by the user.

This works fine, but problems arise when I try and play multiple notes on top of each other. I have tried using multi-threading but the tracks still play one after the other, is there a way that I can play two audio files together, or prehaps merge them?

If not, what else can I do? Generating sine waves is problematic but I am open to suggestions if files won't work...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may need module which can do play at the same time - like `pygame.mixer` - or you have to use module which can merge/mix into one audio - probably [MoviePy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy) or [ffmpeg-python](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/) could merge/mix it

Comment: [Pydub mix 2 sounds with different energy levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368287/pydub-mix-2-sounds-with-different-energy-levels)